# Что означает -> в функции в классе в Python

Tags: python

Я обычно не встречал такую конструкцию и не могу понять что означает -> None в функции.

Приведу пример:

```
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        pass
```

К сожалению не понимаю иногда самых простых вещей извините.

Comment: да уж. Google действительно - самая простая вещь. <https://overcoder.net/q/277766/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-gt-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-python>

Comment: @Сергей не нужно посылать всех в гугл

Comment: @insolor, идея в том, чтобы люди хоть какой-то поиск учились делать самостоятельно, а не начинали сразу спрашивать. Google - наиболее подходящий (=простой) инструмент. И я пробовал эмулировать действия спрашивающего путём простого запроса "-> Python что это?" тут на SO через поиск и через Google. Google выдал её почти сразу, а с SO - не получилось.

Comment: @Сергей 99 процентов вопросов решается поиском через гугл. Это не означает, что не нужно задавать вопросы здесь. Если всех отсылать к гуглу, тогда зачем вообще нужен этот сайт? В целом, здесь не принято отправлять участников в гугл.

Comment: @insolor если все существующие вопросы так или иначе уже рассмотрены в результатах поиска гугла — то в общем-то да, этот сайт и не нужен

Comment: @insolor, вам виднее - вы тут старожил. Не буду отправлять. Хотя логика спорная. Нет большой разницы: а) поленился ли человек сделать домашнее задание и просто разместил тут задачу, б) взял чужой код, разбираться не стал, пишет тут "исправьте", в) нашел новый элемент языка, разбираться вообще не стал, разместил вопрос тут. Надо все же хоть самому чуть разобраться, а потом задать вопросы по существу, иначе появляются безинициативные сотрудники, отнимающие время у коллег и убивающие свою карьеру. Ваша статья про "->" великолепна, в 2017 такую информацию,вероятно, было трудно найти. Сейчас 2022.